# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have tried to implement Many to Many relationship width extras columns with in Spring data JPA framework,
I have three class involved in this relation : Product , CategoryPrice, ProductPrice 
I have used the Embeddable composite key approche to map the relation:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class ProductPricePrimaryKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "idproduct")
    private Long productId;

    @Column(name = "idpricecategory")
    private Long idpricecategory;

    public ProductPricePrimaryKey() {
    }

    public ProductPricePrimaryKey(
            Integer productId,
            Integer categoryPriceId) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.idpricecategory = categoryPriceId;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        ProductPricePrimaryKey that = (ProductPricePrimaryKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(productId, that.productId) &&
                Objects.equals(idpricecategory, that.idpricecategory);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(productId, idpricecategory);
    }
}
```

ProductPrice Class (Join Table)

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Entity
@Table(name = "productprice")
public class ProductPrice implements Serializable {


    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductPricePrimaryKey productPricePrimaryKey;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("productId")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("idpricecategory")
    private PriceCategory priceCategory;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;

// Getter and Setters 

}
```

// Product Class

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idproduct")
    private Long idProduct;
    @Column(name = "namefr")
    private String nameFR;
    @Column(name = "namear")
    private String nameAR;


 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER ,mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<ProductPrice> productPrices = new HashSet<>();

    // Other attributes 

    // Getters and Setters
    }
```

PriceCategory  table

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pricecategory")
public class PriceCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idpricecategory")
    private Long idPriceCategory;

    @Column(name = "percentage")
    private Integer percontage;

    @Column(name = "observation")
    private String observation;


    // Relationship
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER , mappedBy = "priceCategory")
    private Set<ProductPrice> productPrices = new HashSet<>();

}
```

I thinked that may be a bug : 
But i want to see advices from professionals

Here is the stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [1] value by reflection : [class com.abdofx.demo.model.stock.ProductPricePrimaryKey.idpricecategory] setter of com.abdofx.demo.model.stock.ProductPricePrimaryKey.idpricecategory; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [1] value by reflection : [class com.abdofx.demo.model.stock.ProductPricePrimaryKey.idpricecategory] setter of com.abdofx.demo.model.stock.ProductPricePrimaryKey.idpricecategory

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:507)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.abdofx.demo.repository.stocktest.productpricetest.insertProductPrice(productpricetest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [1] value by reflection : [class com.abdofx.demo.model.stock.ProductPricePrimaryKey.idpricecategory] setter of com.abdofx.demo.model.stock.ProductPricePrimaryKey.idpricecategory
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component$ValueGenerationPlan.execute(Component.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.generate(CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:800)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:304)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:41)
    ... 72 more
```

Comment: Hibernate complains about the lack of setter method for `idpricecategory` . The way it uses reflection requires setter methods for the fields (also consider adding getter methods) .

Comment: but the setter and getter of idpricecategory exist, why is hibernate complaint about this field

Comment: The missing setter should be in the `ProductPricePrimaryKey` class .

Comment: there is no missing setter in ProductPricePrimaryKey, it exists that class